# How to create a dynamic SQL table ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, object-oriented-database

I am trying to create a website using ASP.NET, Microsoft SQL and C#. I am creating a food recipe site where the users can upload their own recipes. In the recipe submitting form there are the ingredients section and the steps section. The data collected in the form is sent to a SQL DB table. However the number of steps and ingredients  is indefinite. So how to I add it to the table. Is it possible to create a dynamic table. Any kind of help is much appreciated.

PS. I know this question may sound stupid to many developers out there but I'm still a newb. thanks :)

Comment: Considered learning some database basics? As in: I totally fail why you would need to generate a TABLE in order to  store an "infinite" possible number of ingredients and steps. That is like buying a new car for every possible route you want to drive and shows a fundamental issue with your idea how database work.

Comment: You're not a newb. You have as much knowledge of databases as my wife. You need to teach yourself the basics of one to many relationships. A recipe table and a recipesteps table eh? This site lately seems to have become a magnet for people with absolutely no idea to ask ludicrously general questions.

Answer (score 0):

Think about redesigning your database. If you have columns for each step, that could be a design flaw. Think about how you can avoid the problem altogether by using a different database design.